# React Native Firebase async function exiting when there's a where clause

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, infinite-scroll

This works

```
  const getCatListings = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    let snapshot = await listingsRef.orderBy('expires').limit(20).get();

    if (!snapshot.empty) {
      let newListings = [];

      setLastDoc(snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]);

      for (let i = 0; i < snapshot.docs.length; i++) {
        newListings.push(snapshot.docs[i].data());
      }

      setData(newListings);
    } else {
      setLastDoc(null);
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  }
```

But when I add the `.where("categoryID", "==", category.id)` it exits the function after `setIsLoading(true)` without throwing any errors to explain why.

`let snapshot = await listingsRef.where("categoryID", "==", category.id).orderBy('expires').limit(20).get();`

I read that "==" doesn't need an orderBy on categoryID, but tried it all the same. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you're having where and orderby both in a single firebase query, you need to add an index in firebase to support this query.

You can read it in the [official documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).